# Return view with ViewModel after ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i call an action from ajax function, get my ViewModel in it and then try to open new view with other ViewModel but redirectToAction and return view aren't working. Other answers i saw only got to opening other view without sending ViewModel with it

ajax call

```
$("#delete").click(function () {
                var model = $("#forma").serialize();

                console.log("delete", model);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteDevices", "package")',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: model,
                    success: function (result) {
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
```

and contorller which does nothing

```
 public ActionResult DeleteDevices(PackageDevicesViewModel viewModel)
        {
//model processing here
        return View(NewModel);
}
```

Comment: remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` and change `dataType: 'html'` (or remove that as well) - your not returning `json`

Comment: And I suggest that this should be a POST rather that a GET (the name of the method suggest your modifying data)

Comment: What errors do you see in your console window,

Comment: @Reddy ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined only this on page load and nothing on ajax call

Comment: That means you have not included the Jquery library in your layout page. You will find a file in the scripts folder of your project, else if not then add this line of code in your head tag `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`  and try again

Answer (score 0):

change

```
data: model
```

to

```
data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($("form").serializeArray()))
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).